# Как программно добавить Fragment в Content.xml, который инклудом помещен в Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Создаю свое первое приложение. Краткий смысл: выводит список приборов с сопутствующей информацией, при щелчке на элементе списка - открывает детальную информацию на выбранный прибор. Разработку начал с отображения детальной информации. DetailActivity содержит внутри себя Fragment, который в xml разметке activity помещается строчкой:

```
<include layout="@layout/content" />
```

Содержание самого файла content.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.user.labtmp.DetailDeviceFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail_device" />
```

Написал отображение детальной информации и принялся за вывод ListView в имеющийся фрагмент. В манифест прописал лаунчер на новую ListViewActivity, которую привязал к XML представлению DetailActivity.xml. 
Код новой активити:

```
public class ListViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
        if (fragment==null) {
            fragment = new ListViewFragment();// Фрагмент с отображением списка

        fm.beginTransaction().
                add(R.id.fragment, fragment)
                .commit();
        }

    }
}
```

Я думал что фрагмент менеджер должен заменить строчку Content.xml:

```
android:name="com.example.user.labtmp.DetailDeviceFragment"
```

на наш фрагмент. Но запуск показывает, что вместо ListViewFragment отображается DetailDeviceFragment. Если вручную в контенте меняю на наш фрагмент, то все отображается правильно.    С этим связано два вопроса:
 1. Неужели нет способа программно менять content.xml и придется для каждого 
фрагмента писать свой ContentXFragment.xml?
 2. Почему Fragment manager не меняет Content.xml?

**UPD.**
Удалил из content.xml строчку с тегом name. Теперь фрагмент не имеет привязки к макету. Заменил метод add на метод replace  у FragmentManager. Вывел логи на методы onAttach, onCreateView, onCreate. В эмуляторе приложение не запускается. В логах не фиксируется даже метод onAttach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В документации на ListFragment сказано:
To do this, your view hierarchy must contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code).
Поэтому я изменил код своего include (content.xml) в соответствии с этим требованием. Я добавил контейнер ConstraintLayout и в него вставил ListView с строчкой:

```
android:id="@id/android:list"
```

В адаптер передал id ConstraintLayout'а :

```
fm.beginTransaction().
                add(R.id.frameContainer, fragment)
                .commit();
```

после этого все заработало так, как должно быть.